# Not able to install dependencies in my flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am trying to install image_picker and firbase_storage in my flutter project. But whatever version I try to install, it fails. and gives error like this -

```
Because image_picker >=0.3.0 requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4 <2.0.0 and image_picker <0.3.0 requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0, image_picker is forbidden.
```

I have tried out installing every version but not able to install even a single version.

Flutter doctor -v is working fine and following is the content of my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: timepass
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
    sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
flutter_secure_storage: ^3.1.3
image_picker: ^0.1.4
firebase_storage: ^0.2.0
location: ^1.4.1
graphql_flutter: ^0.9.1
flutter:
    sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
```

Comment: If my answer does not help please post your `dependencies:` from `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: dependencies:
    flutter_secure_storage: ^3.1.3
    image_picker: ^0.5.0
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please edit your question and put your whole `pubspec.yaml` there. Also please post add the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: please post add the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this kind of dependency issues is that just let the pub to fetch the appropriate version if you are facing any issues or conflicts with dependency.

Add the dependency on `pubspec.yaml` as below

```
dependencies:
  image_picker: any
```

or

```
dependencies:
  image_picker:
```

Then check the `pubspec.lock` file and find the version number.

In this case, you may get

```
image_picker:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: image_picker
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.5.0"
```

Then you can modify `pubspec.yaml` as

```
dependencies:
  image_picker: ^0.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow a newer `image_picker` version.

Try

```
dependencies:
  image_picker:
```

or

```
dependencies:
  image_picker: ^0.5.0
```